# Problem with validating integer with .matches

Tags: java

I'm trying to make an expression validation method to make sure if the account number passed into the function is valid or not. If Yes it would return true, if false it would return false.

But I'm experiencing an error:

```
Cannot Resolve method(java.lang.string)
```

I have looked over few stackoverflow questions but I can't seem to be figuring out what I'm doing wrong in my code.

```
accountNumber  = integer data type
this.AccountNumber  = integer data type
```

Code:

```
String pattern2 = "^\d{1,10}$" ;
if (!accountNumber.matches(pattern2)) {
    return false;
} else {
    this.AccountNumber = accountNumber;
    return true;
}
```

I'm getting the pattern from 
https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html#ad-output

Comment: `accountNumber` is an integer? You can't use a regular expression on an integer, nor do you need to. All an `int` can hold is a valid sequence of digits (and a negative sign).

Comment: So your basically saying I cannot validate something using the code right now ( with .match method) with a integer data type? If so what do you recommend on using to validate something to check it If its a number thats between 1-10 digit

Comment: You don't seem to understand, so I'll give you a small code example. `System.out.println(String.valueOf(Integer.MAX_VALUE).length());` *or* using **math** `System.out.println(1 + (int) (Math.log(Integer.MAX_VALUE) / Math.log(10)));` - there is no int value that is not a number between 1-10 digits; you might want `if (accountNumber >= 0)`  if you want to prevent ***negative*** values.

Comment: Well I want to check if the integer inputted if is between 5 - 9 digits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code would work *if* `accountNumber` was a String. [`java.lang.String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches-java.lang.String-) has a matches method which can evaluate a String against a regular expression.

But instead you have an integer to work with. So you have two options:

1. Convert the integer to a String, and then your code will work:

```
String converted = String.valueOf(accountNumber); 
String pattern2 = "^\\d{1,10}$" ;
if (!converted.matches(pattern2)) { // use the converted String to compare
    return false;
} else {
    this.AccountNumber = accountNumber;
    return true;
}
```

2. Or, since you're just trying to count the digits, you can just use Math. You state you need to figure out if your integer has between 5 and 9 digits, so therefore it stands to reason that its value is between 10,000 and 999,999,999 (assuming that 9 digits are valid, otherwise drop one of the 9's.) So you could do something like:

```
if ( 10_000 <= accountNumber && accountNumber <= 999_999_999 ) {
  // this meets your condition
} else {
  // the number of digits is wrong.
}
```

(This assumes, of course, that you don't have a negative value in `accountNumber`. Calling `accountNumber = Math.abs(accountNumber)` would resolve that.)

Comment: Also worth mentioning that the `^` and `$` in the pattern are not required, since `String.matches` implicitly tests the whole String value anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your `int` variable to a `String` to do regex matching. Wrap your if condition with `java.util.Objects.toString()` helper method.

```
if (!Objects.toString(accountNumber).matches(pattern2))
```

If the `accountNumber` is already an `Integer` you can just call the `toString()` method directly on the `accountNumber` variable.

You should do some reading on Java Autoboxing/unboxing: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html

Answer (score 0):

accountNumber = integer data type?

integer type don't hava 'matches' method

accountNumber should be String type.

eg:

boolean b = "abc".matches("^\d{1,10}$");